# CertificateServicesClient-CredentialRoaming error 1005

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, credentials

We have a Microsoft Team Foundation Server (Single Server Installation, i.e. Microsoft SQL Server 2008, Microsoft Windows SharePonint Services 3.0) installed on a Windows Server 2008 machine. The TFS works fine, but there are error events logged frequently:

> Log Name:      Application
>
> Source:
>   Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-CredentialRoaming
>
> Event ID:      1005
>
> Level:         Error
>
> Description: Certificate Services Client: Credential Roaming failed to
>   write to the Active Directory. Error code 5 (Access is denied.)

The problem is clear (the error message is quite precise) but I don't have a clue how to fix it! Where has the access to be granted? What permissions have to be set?